# Internet Explorer will not support stop scrolling either by jQuery or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a  overlapping screen (like facebook photo-viewer,) and for now it works fine in chrome, safari and firefox, but i do also need it to work in IE. 
Actually the div overlaps perfect like i want it to, but it allows it to scroll, which I don't want to. So i've tried to use overflow: hidden; when the button is clicked so it will not scroll. It works fine, but now my problem is to allow it to scroll again. I've both tried with overflow: auto and some jquery functions, but it doesn't seems to work. And I've also detected that it won't do jquery such as $(document).ready(function() {  ... });

The code I'm using to overlap:

```
var outercontent = document.getElementById('transparent')
var innercontent = document.getElementById('innercont')
browser = navigator.appName;
explore = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
if(browser == explore) {
    outercontent.style.zIndex = '9989';
    outercontent.style.display = 'block';
    outercontent.style.position = 'absolute';
    outercontent.style.top = '0';
    outercontent.style.left = '0';
    outercontent.style.width = viewportwidth;
    outercontent.style.height = viewportheight;
    outercontent.style.margin = '0';
    outercontent.style.padding = '0';

    innercontent.style.left = '20%';
    innercontent.style.background = 'white';
    innercontent.style.zIndex = '9999';
    innercontent.style.width = '60%';
    innercontent.style.height = '80%';
    innercontent.style.marginBottom = '10%';
    innercontent.style.marginTop = '5%';
    innercontent.style.padding = '10px';

}
```

And inside my html page i have the divs placed :

```
<div id='transparent' style='background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
filter:
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,
StartColorStr='#e5000000',EndColorStr='#e5000000');
text-align: center;'>
    <div id='innercont' style='position: absolute; color: black;'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net is your friend.

Comment: Do you mean like a lightbox with dynamic content within?

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping your content in a `<div>` with `height: 100%; overflow: hidden;` inside of `#innercont`? That should be more controllable.